# In Intel XDK Error: An Error occurred while building the application

Tags: html, intel, intel-xdk

I have just downloaded Intel-XDK version-2611,I have created an app and tested, it was working fine.
But now I was trying to built its final version ,
I had applied icons and splash screens images and then I went toward build options.Then I pushed the code to server and press green button to Build app.But I got the error named in the title of this question.I had built previous, it was working fine, that time I did not apply any image(icon and splash). when I uploaded them I got this error.

[image: pic]

Comment: Click the detailed error log link and near the end there is likely a clue as to the reason for the build error. Once you see the error message you can search the XDK forum, it is likely that others have encountered the same error.

Comment: ok I'll try .. Thank you